# FedEx Tracking via SOAP using TrackService_v8 example file

Tags: php, xml, soap, fedex

I haveing trouble figuring out how to use Fedex's example file on tracking.  I've got it communicateing with their test server, but I'm trying to get 'INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS' information from it.  I can't figure out what syntax, of what to put to include it.  I've found...

```
  <xs:simpleType name="TrackRequestProcessingOptionType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

So I've tried all sorts of variations of stuff like

```
    $request['TrackRequestProcessingOptionType']=array('INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS' => true );
```

but I'm not getting anything extra.  Has anybody used this... what am I missing? I'm just not understanding how it's using the TrackService_v8 file very well.  I'm about to just change tactics and try writing it similar to an Ebay project I did which involved using curl and transmitting XML... although this might be slower...

Full code of request:

```
$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'UserCredential' =>array(
        'Key' => 'asdfasdf', 
        'Password' => 'asdfasasdf'
    )
);
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => 'asdfasdf', 
    'MeterNumber' => 'asdfas'
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => '*** Track Request v8 using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'trck', 
    'Major' => '8', 
    'Intermediate' => '0', 
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['TrackRequestProcessingOptionType']=array('INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS' => true );
$request['SelectionDetails'] = array(
    'CarrierCode' => 'FDXE',
    'PackageIdentifier' => array(
        'Type' => 'TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG',
        'Value' => 'asdfasdf' // Replace 'XXX' with a valid tracking identifier
    )
);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It says it requires a string, true is a boolean. Also shouldn't it be `$request['ProcessingOptions']`? Try `$request['ProcessingOptions'] = array('TrackRequestProcessingOptionType' => 'true');` More info here: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/product/WebServices/MyWebHelp/Transactions/WS/r_TrackRequestElements.html

Comment: Thanks Ben.  You solved it, or pointed me in the wrong direction.  Maybe post an anwser.... but this made it work:  $request['ProcessingOptions']='INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS';  When I put in an array like all the other stuff it just yelled about it being in an array.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. :) If you aren't already, try putting it in a `try{}catch(SoapFault $e){echo $e->getMessage();}` as this will return most errors.

Comment: I don't think that the example code you've provided is the working, self-contained example that is required to ask a question on Stackoverflow.... .